# ddply() is saying there is some missing value in my data when there is none, any idea why?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to use the ddply() instead of tapply(). But it is showing some error which I'm unable to fix.

```r
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
ddply(birthwt$bwt,birthwt$race,mean)
```

Error in if (empty(.data)) return(.data) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not due to missing data, it's because the syntax used for `ddply` is incorrect. The first argument should be the data frame, then the variables to group by, then the summary function.

So something like:

```
ddply(birthwt, ~race, summarize, Mean = mean(bwt))

  race     Mean
1    1 3102.719
2    2 2719.692
3    3 2805.284
```

However I'd consider looking at [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html), the more modern successor to `plyr`. The same operation would look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
birthwt %>% 
  group_by(race) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(bwt))
```